# Recurring Error in Eclipse "Could not delete '/some/file/in/war/dir' fix ..., then try refreshing..."

Tags: java, eclipse, build, delete-file

I have looked at the existing related posts here and although they do explain how to workaround the problem once it happens, I am trying to stop the problem from happening in the first place. I've tried to use sysinternals procmon to track down what's holding the lock on the file without success.

I would greatly appreciate any help in tracking down the actual cause of this recurring annoyance.

EDIT:
I'm not doing anything in particular to cause this, I'm just working as normal (which means autobuild and refreshes are happening) and a few times during the day, this will happen, necessitating use of the workarounds found elsewhere such as manually deleting the files and rebuilding

Comment: Please explain in more detail what operation you are performing when you get this error. Your question doesn't contain a great deal of detail for those of us who haven't been researching the problem all morning :-)

Comment: I'm not doing anything, I'm just working as normal (which means autobuild and refreshes are happening) and a few times during the day, this will happen, necessitating use of the workarounds found elsewhere such as manually deleting the files and rebuilding

Comment: So you are just coding away and occasionally this happens as a result of Eclipse's "Build automatically" setting? Please tell us more about what sort of Eclipse project you are working on.